# How can i sort char[] array case insensitive?

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to sort a `char[]` array in Java.

I tried using a `List` but it didn't work perfectly.
I also tried using `Arrays.sort(dizimiz,String.case_insensive_order)`, but I got an error.

Here is the code I have:

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter text:");
String str=sc.nextLine();

//  toCharArray() splits the string into a character array
char[] chars=str.toCharArray();

Arrays.sort(chars);
for (char c : chars) {
    System.out.println(c);
}
```

What method can I use to do this?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T[],%20java.util.Comparator%29

Comment: use String.equalsIgnoreCase()

Comment: "it didn't work perfectly" and "i got error" are not problem descriptions. (In any language.) *How* did it not work? *What* error did you get?

Comment: Why would you want to sort the characters in a character array?  Why not put them in a [`UnicodeSet`](http://www.icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/UnicodeSet.html)?

Answer (score 2):

The comparator `String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER` is for strings only, but you tried using it with a char array. If you want to use it, you have to convert the string into an array of strings (each string containing a single character).

```
String[] chars = str.split("");
Arrays.sort(chars, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);

for (String c : chars) {
    System.out.println(c);
}
```

Comment: This certainly is a lot easier than my answer. But I wonder which answer is more efficient at 1 million characters?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not care about the case you can just change

```
char[] dizimiz = str.toCharArray();
```

to

```
char[] dizimiz = str.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
```

That will accomplish your question

> How can i sort char[] array case insensitive?

If there is something else I am missing here please let me know and I will update my answer.

As per the comments below I have made a rough code for you to sort and retain the output with the proper casing.

```
    char[] dizimiz = str.toCharArray();
    char[] lc = str.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
    char temp;
    Boolean done;
    if (lc.length > 1) do {
        done = true;
        for (int i = lc.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        if (lc[i] < lc[i - 1]) {
            temp = lc[i - 1];
            lc[i - 1] = lc[i];
            lc[i] = temp;
            temp = dizimiz[i - 1];
            dizimiz[i - 1] = dizimiz[i];
            dizimiz[i] = temp;
            done = false;
           }
        }
    } while (!done);
```

Comment: No, that won't. If the OP has b, A, a, C, he wants A, a, b, C as a result, not a, a, b, c

Comment: Yes its true.I want A,a,b,C.How can i sort like this.

Comment: @JBNizet I updated code to do that. I know there is easier ways but I like to see how it is being done in the for loop.

Comment: @user3542379 I updated my answer it will output the way you want it.

Comment: @CodeCamper: You're trying to reimplement a sort algorithm, and your algorithm isn't correct. You'd better transform the char array to a Character array, sort it using the standard algorithm and a custom Comparator<Character>, and then transform the Character array back to a char array.

Comment: @JBNizet it is working for me, what is not correct about it?

Comment: I typed zak and my output is akz. Did you notice the boolean and the while loop? Also if I search zakZAKzak it outputs aAakKkzZz. Isn't this the intended output?

Comment: Sorry, I misread the algorithm and didn't see the outer loop. I wouldn't rewrite my own, slow sorting algorithm though, and would use the standard one from the JDK.